# Does Silent Roll work with Critical Charge?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Critical Charge is a perk in the One-handed constellation, and Silent Roll is a perk in the Sneak constellation. In particular, I'm wondering if it's possible in the latest version of Skyrim. I've seen at least one video where someone is able to do it along with an attack-spam glitch to move quickly.

If it is possible, what input is necessary to perform it? I can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works, but there is a huge bug: you will only get the extra critical damage if you've invested at least two perks in the Bladesman perk.

[This article](http://theskyrimblog.ning.com/group/glitches/forum/topics/how-critical-damage-for-swords-works-in-skyrim?xg_source=activity) describes why this is so and how Bladesman interacts with Critical Charge

**TL;DR**
 Put at least two perk points in Bladesman and you'll start seeing results. Combine that with a perk in backstab and you should see noticeable damage improvement in your successful rolling sneak attacks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to roll and swing a weapon at the same time.

Comment: Was it patched?

Comment: @NiteCyper dunno, as far as I'm aware it has never been possible.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHHvg5XgCdw First hit for "silent roll critical charge"